# Any idea for using DISTINCT with this kode

Tags: php, mysql, database, split, distinct

My brain stuck for do this ..

i've database

```
first table : master_code

id_bab | nama_bab | id_pasal | nama_pasal | id_topik | nama topik | kode 
01     | AAA      | 01       |  ABAB      |  01      |  ADAC      | 010101 
01     | AAA      | 02       |  ACAC      |  01      |  ASAC      | 010201 
03     | MMM      | 01       |  ADAD      |  01      |  AEAC      | 030101 
04     | LLL      | 01       |  AFAF      |  01      |  AWAC      | 040101
```

kode is composite from id_bab id_pasal id_topik

```
second table : clasification

id_surat | id_ayat | id_klasifikasi 
098      |  01     | 010101
094      |  02     | 010201
097      |  21     | 010101
099      |  11     | 010101
091      |  02     | 030101
092      |  01     | 040101




i want to display like this (to split and make it distinct)
010101->> ABAB - ADAC
010201->> ACAC - ASAC
030101->> ADAD - AEAC
040101->> AFAF - AWAC
```

any idea for making query ? my brain was stuck

Comment: 1. 2nd table is for ? .....2.kode is unique anyway - why DISTINCT ? provide better example

Comment: There is no column which will match these 2 tables. I mean there no column which I can interpret for communication

Comment: i'm forget to say . distinct is for display output for once @chenchuk

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am assuming that you want to output ABAB - ADAC insead of id_klasifikasi's value. Here's one way you could do this. If you that's not what you desire, please update your question with expected output.

```
select 
    c.*, 
    concat(nama_pasal, ' - ', nama_topik) as result1, 
    concat(id_klasifikasi, '->> ', nama_pasal, ' - ', nama_topik) as result2
from clasification c 
join master_code m on m.kode = c.id_klasifikasi

will result in 

id_surat | id_ayat | id_klasifikasi | result1     | result2
098      | 01      | 010101         | ABAB - ADAC | 010101->> ABAB - ADAC
094      | 02      | 010201         | ACAC - ASAC | 010201->> ACAC - ASAC
097      | 21      | 010101         | ABAB - ADAC | 010101->> ABAB - ADAC
099      | 11      | 010101         | ABAB - ADAC | 010101->> ABAB - ADAC
091      | 02      | 030101         | ADAD - AEAC | 030101->> ADAD - AEAC
092      | 01      | 040101         | AFAF - AWAC | 040101->> AFAF - AWAC
```

Comment: sorry about my question make you confused @zedfoxus ... i want too display it once .. should i put the distinct ? for ABAB-ADAC just once display

Comment: Just create a nicely formatted input dataset and output dataset you want in Excel. Take a screenshot and put it in your question. Let me know and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @tara Were you able to solve your question or do you need further assistance?